# Macbook Pro 2015 barfed during Boot Camp partitioning, rebooted to uninitialized APFS drive

Tags: bootcamp, partition, data-recovery, apfs, diskutil

I was trying to run Boot Camp to have access to the windows Steam library. Boot Camp kept failing and it would then hang on "error: please wait while we reset the partitions to the usual configuration," more or less. This hung forever and I ended up just quitting Boot Camp and deleting the Windows partition that was created. I thought that maybe getting the latest MacOS would fix bootcamp so I upgraded from Sierra to Catalina but got the same error, only this time, after quitting Boot Camp during the "let's clean up the partitioning" phase, I restarted and now I have the question mark folder at boot and eventually arrive at this:

​
[image]
​
What makes me hopeful is that 365gb sounds like the amount I left allotted for MacOS, so hopefully my data is just sitting there but it's "uninitialized." The "mount" button does nothing.

​
My other thought: can I just buy an enclosure and grab my important files? Would they just show up in finder?

Comment: I can offer you to access your MBP remotely and check the internal disk. This requires to install a **full** macOS Catalina to **either** a **thumb drive (16 GB or better 32 GB)** or another **external disk** and install some remote desktop app (like [TeamViewer](https://www.teamviewer.com)) to this new system.